# Issue with a function reversing byte order

Tags: c, byte, bit, can-bus

I'm working on CAN Frames, in order to decode their payload, I have to reverse their order.
The payload is a `uint8_t payload[8]` (8 bytes in the payload) read in the can frame with an external function that works properly.
I have this function :

```
static inline uint64_t reverse_byte_order(uint64_t x)
{
    x = (x & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF) << 32 | (x & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32;
    x = (x & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) << 16 | (x & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000) >> 16;
    x = (x & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF) << 8  | (x & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00) >> 8;
    return x;
}
```

So basically i just call `reverse_byte_order(*(uint64_t*)payload)`, but after some tests we couldn't get the right messages after decoding, and realized the problem came from this function.

One test that doesn't work is putting `payload[0]=0x40` and everything else to 0x00. The output is 0, whereas it should be 0x 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00.

Any helped would be appreciated.

Edit : Here is a MCVE you can copy paste into your IDE if you want to do some testing :

```c
#include <stdint.h>

static inline uint64_t reverse_byte_order(uint64_t x)
{
    printf("\nInitial x : %016x", x);
    x = (x & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF) << 32 | (x & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32;
    printf("\nFirst x : %016x", x); //in our example here it doesn't work anymore as x is 0
    x = (x & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) << 16 | (x & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000) >> 16;
    printf("\nSecond x : %016x", x);
    x = (x & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF) << 8  | (x & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00) >> 8;
    printf("\nFinal x : %016x", x);
    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    uint8_t data[8];
    data[0]=0x11;
    data[1]=0x00;
    data[2]=0x00;
    data[3]=0x00;
    data[4]=0x00;
    data[5]=0x00;
    data[6]=0x00;
    data[7]=0x00;


    uint64_t indata = reverse_byte_order(*(uint64_t*)data);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How do you call the function and how are parameters defined and initialized? Please don't describe, but show what you are doing.

Comment: Your payload is not necessarily aligned properly for uint64 access.

Comment: Do you have `bswap_64()` available?

Comment: @Gerhardh Not sure of what you mean, but from the tests calling *(uint64_t*)payload gives me the expected value. I'll put the code of my MCVE in a new response
Shawn, I'm using a library coded by someone else (I didn't write this function) and I guess that if he didn't use bswap there must be a reason

Comment: Please add the MCVE to the question body, not in comments. You can use the `edit` button below your question. I don't know what you mean with expected value. `(uint64_t)payload` is invalid as it makes an integer from an array/pointer.

Comment: Gerhardh meant: please show what is payload here `reverse_byte_order(*(uint64_t*)payload)` . If it's an array of something else than uint64_t, then casting its address to uint64_t is wrong.

Comment: MCVE is added to the body through editing, hope it is clear enough

Comment: `%016x` Are your `unsigned int` variables 64 bit? Otherwise the format specifier will not print all bytes.

Comment: A `char data[8]` array normally has an alignment requirement for 1 byte while a `uint64_t` has 4 or 8 bytes. Some CPUs do not read the correct values (or even create segfault) )if you use a pointer that is not properly aligned. You could try using a union holding both the array and a `uint64_t` member

Comment: Why exactly do you need to reverse the payload? That sounds strange. CAN doesn't specify endianess etc of the payload.

Comment: BTW: Unless your CPU has a native 64 bit data type, I would guess that a simple loop over the array might be better solution than this.

Comment: As for your example, it is flawed because `%x` assumes `unsigned int` which is 32 bits. Use `PRIx64` from inttypes.h instead.

Comment: Also... is there a reason why `for(size_t i=0; i<8; i++) { dst[8-1-i] = src[i]; }` doesn't work? It will be hard to argue about the 64 bit version being more effective, especially on embedded systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failure in the test code shown can be entirely explained by the fact that `uint64_t` values are printed using an `x` conversion specifier, which is for an `unsigned`. The resulting behavior is not defined by the C standard, but converting just the low 32 bits of the `uint64_t`, and thus printing zero for a value with zeros in the low 32 bits, is a natural result.

The solution for this is to use a correct conversion specifier:

- Include the header `<inttypes.h>`.
- In place of `x` inside the quoted string, end the quoted string and use `PRIx64`. This is a macro that expands to a quoted string with the correct conversion specifier for a `uint64_t` to be converted to hexadecimal, and the quoted string will be concatenated with neighboring strings. For example, change `"\nInitial x : %016x"` to `"\nInitial x : %016" PRIx64`.

Additional problems in the code shown include:

- The behavior of converting a pointer to `uint64_t *` is not defined by the C standard if the alignment is not correct for a `uint64_t *`.
- Using memory defined as an array of `uint8_t` as if it were a `uint64_t` violates the aliasing rules in C 2018 6.5 7, and the resulting behavior is not defined by the C standard.
- `<stdio.h>` is not included.
- Lines should be printed with a trailing `\n` rather than a preceding `\n`. This is because `\n` causes a line-buffered stream to be flushed: When there is a trailing `\n`, the output is printed immediately, whereas, with only preceding `\n`, the output may be held in a buffer indefinitely.

A defined way to reinterpret memory as another type is to copy the bytes:

```
uint64_t x;
memcpy(&x, data, sizeof x);
```

After the above, `x` can be passed to `reverse_byte_order` as a `uint64_t`. (Since `memcpy` is declared in `<string.h>`, that header should be included.)

Also be sure to enable warnings in your compiler and to pay attention to them. Most compilers would have warned about the mismatch between the conversion specifier in the format string and the argument type, as well as the missing `<stdio.h>` header.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `memcpy()` to copy your array of `uint8_t` values to a `uint64_t` value, your byte swap function works without any possible alignment issues:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

static inline uint64_t reverse_byte_order(uint64_t x) {
  x = (x & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF) << 32 | (x & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32;
  x = (x & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFF) << 16 | (x & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000) >> 16;
  x = (x & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FF) << 8 | (x & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00) >> 8;
  return x;
}

int main(void) {
  uint8_t data[8];

  _Static_assert(sizeof(data) == sizeof(uint64_t), "You have a weird CPU");

  data[0] = 0x11;
  data[1] = 0x00;
  data[2] = 0x00;
  data[3] = 0x00;
  data[4] = 0x00;
  data[5] = 0x00;
  data[6] = 0x00;
  data[7] = 0x00;

  uint64_t num;
  memcpy(&num, data, sizeof num);
  uint64_t indata = reverse_byte_order(num);

  printf("%#" PRIx64 " reversed is %#" PRIx64 "\n", num, indata);

  return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running this version prints `0x11 reversed is 0x1100000000000000` on a little-endian system.

Note using the `<inttypes.h>` macros to get the right format specifiers for `printf()`. If you're using `%x` for printing `uint64_t` values on a system where `unsigned int` is 32 bits, that's got a lot to do with you seeing the wrong numbers. Your compiler should be warning you about such things. If not, turn up the options (`-Wall -Wextra` is a good set for gcc and clang).